# Angularjs select: How to get the position of the selected item and set default selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I saw in another SO question this trick to get the position of the selected item:

```
<select
  ng-model="index_selected_item"
  ng-options="idx as choice.name for (idx, choice) in items">
</select>
```

Now I want the selection list to start displaying the first item as selected, but I am not able to do it.

I have tried using `ng-init` to set `index_selected_item = 0`, but the default selected option remains blank.

Thanks!

Comment: From the manual ~ *"`ngModel` compares by reference, not value"*. You would have to initialise `index_selected_item` to one of the items in `items`, by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it the way it is shown in here:

http://codepen.io/paulbhartzog/pen/xBFir

```
$scope.options = [
    { label: 'one', value: 1 },
    { label: 'two', value: 2 }
];

$scope.selected_by_reference = $scope.options[1];
```